# T3 framework with custom font - not working on mobiles

Tags: joomla-3.x

I've been asked by a customer to match the font on mobiles to that on the desktop, I'm a bit out of touch with compatibility at the mo, but as far as i am aware if the browser cannot render the font then it chooses the next best thing.

Now, the customer is using '[expletus sans][1]' on the site, yet on mobiles it displays differently to the desktop version. This isn't apparent in dev tools you actually have to check on a mobile, so I cant check it with dev tools to see which font it is using. So:

1. Is there a way to check which font is loading on mobiles accurately from a desktop/laptop
2. Can anyone advise of a site where i can check browser compatibility with specific fonts
3. Any idea how I can load this font on mobiles?

The site is can be found [here][2]

Thank you in advance
D

Comment: If an answer provides a solution to your problem it's good etiquette, and good manners, to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @SethWarburton I hadn't come back to this one - oops, thanks for the prompt :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the the site is not loading Expletus Sans, so it's never used. Your template css includes:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Expletus Sans', cursive;
}
```

But, there is no `@font-face` declaration that actually loads that font, so the fallback specified is used instead. In this case the only fallback specified is a system cursive font which desktop OSs typically have but mobile OSs typically do not.

The solution is to use @font-face declarations in your css to actually load the webfont files (which I assume you have). I'd recommend [the new bulletproof font-face syntax](http://blog.fontspring.com/2011/02/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax/).